# How to decrease numbers from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, console

There are numbers in an array like 54321

`array = ["54321"] ;`

Now how can I print in console

1. 54321
2. 5432
3. 543
4. 54
5. 5

I don't want to print it manually, I want to print it dynamically..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is only 1 number in that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = ["54321"];


const print = ([x]) => {
  if (x.length === 0) return;
  console.log(x);
  print([x.slice(0, -1)]);
}

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the string into array and the use `reduce` function

```
ler arr = array[0].split('');

let result = arr.reduce((acc,i) => { 
                           acc.newarr.push(arr.slice(0,acc.counter).join(''));
                           acc.counter--;
                           return acc;
                         }, 
                       {newarr:[],counter:5});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = ["54321"];

const un_print = ([str]) =>
  Array.from(
    { length: str.length },
    (_, i) => (i + 1) + '. ' + str.slice(0, str.length - i)
  )
    .forEach((v) => console.log(v));

un_print(array);
```